# Design pattern for inheriting same classes from two different superclasses

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I am aware that the title is not very clear.

I have a class called Plot, and there are 2 classes which inherit from Plot.

```
class Plot
{
}

class DynamicPlot : public Plot
{
}

class StaticPlot : public Plot
{
}
```

and i want to add some classes called PhasePlot, RPMPlot vs. Also I want that these classes can be Dynamic or Static.

So, the first thing that comes to my mind is:

```
class DynamicPhasePlot : public DynamicPlot 
{
}

class DynamicRPMPlot : public DynamicPlot 
{
}

class StaticPhasePlot : public StaticPlot 
{
}

class StaticRPMPlot : public StaticPlot 
{
}
```

which seems not a very good solution. I searched for the decorator pattern but i think it doesn't fit my needs. However, i am not really sure.

Comment: When you have Pilot as Parent class of all then where is issue of 2 super classes?

Comment: The problem is, i don't want to inherit from both StaticPlot and DynamicPlot whenever i decide to create a new PhasePlot,RPMPlot, ShiftPlot etc class.

Comment: then you can inherit from Pilot, its a design decision. I dont see any problem here.

Comment: You aren't inheriting from both! Not getting you at all, but I suspect inheritance is the wrong choice, and you want IStatic and IDynamic interfaces, or perhaps ISomething and then inject a delegate class to get static or dynamic behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunate that you does not give use-case for the plots (and the context or concern for the dynamic / static). However, the `Interface`, `Decorator` or `Composition over Inheritance (strategy pattern)` is applicable here.

### Interfaces:

```
interface IPlot //this is optional
interface IDynamicPlot : IPlot
interface IStaticPlot : IPlot
// depending on context, the IPhasePlot can be defined as 
// IDynamicPhasePlot inherited from IDynamicPlot. Same as for static.
interface IPhasePlot : IPlot
interface IRPMPlot : IPlot
class Plot : IPlot
class DynamicPlot : IDynamicPlot
//etc
```

### Strategy Pattern:

Use this if the derived plot has dependency to `Dynamic` or `Static`. It acts as facade class.

```
class DynamicRPMPlot{
    IDynamicPlot dynamicPlot = new DynamicPlot(); //you can do constructor injection here
    IRPMPlot rPMPlot = new RPMPlot(); //you can do constructor injection here

    public void DoSomething(){
        dynamicPlot.DoSomething();
        // you can also migrate the implementation of RPMPlot to here,
        //if it has different cases for dynamic or static
        rPMPlot.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

### Decorator Pattern:

Use this if the `RPM` and `dynamic` is separated in concern.

```
class RPMPlot : IRPMPlot {
    RPMPlot(IPlot decorated){
        // can place null guard here
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }
    IPlot decorated;

    public void DoSomething(){
        decorated.DoSomething(); //you can change the sequence
        //implementation of rpmplot
    }
}

void ConsumePlot(){
    IPlot plot = new RPMPlot(new DynamicPlot());
    plot.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic or Static is the behaviour of a Plot. So, DynamicPlot is a Plot with dynamic behavior and StaticPlot is a Plot with static behaviour. Instead of creating new classes such as DynamicPlot or StaticPlot one can use StrategyPattern to set this behavior dynamically.

```
public enum PlotBehavior
{
   None,
   Dynamic,
   Static
}

public class Plot
{
   private PlotBehavior m_Behavior;
   public Plot()
   {
   }
   public SetBehavior(PlotBehavior ieBehavior)
   {
     this.m_Behavior = ieBhavior;
   }
}
```

Now, our Plot class can be instantiated and used as both Dynamic or Static plot. Now, we can subclass this to more specific classes as below.

```
public PhasePlot: public Plot
{
}

public RPMPlot: public Plot
{
}
```

You get the idea!